# How to add CSS files to app.css in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, sass, bower, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I use Laravel 5 and Elixir.

I have `app.scss` which imports `_bootstrap.csss` (installed by bower), and these files are compiled to one file `public/css/app.css`.

Also I have some CSS files in other dependencies (installed by bower), and I want to add them to `public/css/app.css`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to rename your `.css` file as a `.scss` file, then you can import the new `.scss` file into the `app.scss` file using the same method `_bootstrap.scss` is imported.

```
@import "path/to/css/file.scss";
```

Comment: This file is installed with bower. It's a dependency. I shouldn't rename or patch dependency files.

Comment: True, I didn't notice that in your question. In the past I've created a new `scss` file and imported `app.scss` and other CSS/SCSS files I want compiled in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

In you app.scss file you can import both formats .scss and .css

To import a SCSS file this is the sintax: (without extension)

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Instead to import a CSS file you have to add the .css extension

```
@import "~jquery-ui/themes/base/core.css";
```